# Find all customers who have both an account and a loan at the Perryridge branch

Tags: sql

I have some tables:

- "branch" table(branch_name, branch_city, assets)
- "customer" table(customer_name, customer_street, customer_city)
- "account" table (account_number, branch_name, balance)
- "loan"table (loan_number, branch_name, amount)
- "depositor"table (customer_name, account_number)
- "borrower" table (customer_name, loan_number)

Now I want to find all customers who have both an account and a loan at the Perryridge branch.

the SQL query that I wrote is

```
SELECT distinct customer_name 
FROM borrower, loan
WHERE borrower.loan_number = loan.loan_number 
      AND branch_name = 'Perryridge' 
      AND (branch_name, customer_name )     
          IN (SELECT branch_name, customer_name 
             FROM depositor, account
             WHERE depositor.account_number = account.account_number )
```

I want to know is there any other simpler SQL query can complete the same question, such as using TABLE UNION.

Comment: Tag the database please

Comment: what's the difference between borrower and customer tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try this updated script




SELECT DISTINCT
  customer_name
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN depositor d
  ON d.customer_name=c.customer_name
inner join accounts a on d.account_number = a.account_number
 INNER JOIN borrower b
  ON b.customer_name = c.customer_name
INNER JOIN loan l
  ON l.loan_number = b.loan_number
WHERE l.branch_name = a.branch_name 
AND l.branch_name = 'Perryridge'
```

Comment: but customer table does not have account_number

Comment: Did you update your tables again? There was an accnt number over customer

Comment: In that case depositor customer name to customer table and despitor accnt number to accnt table

Answer (score 0):

SELECT distinct customer_name 
FROM borrower, loan
WHERE borrower.loan_number = loan.loan_number 
      AND branch_name = 'Perryridge' 
      AND (branch_name, customer_name )
          IN (SELECT branch_name, customer_name 
             FROM depositor, account
             WHERE depositor.account_number = account.account_number )